# Derivative of : $y=\int_0^{x^2} (t^3+1)^{1/2} \,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

> Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx},$ where 
>   $$y=\int_0^{x^2} (t^3+1)^{1/2} \,dt$$

I have tried solving this question but do not know how to start. 
This is from my Calc $1$ practice exam but have no answers for it

Comment: It is unclear what you should do, but do you mean to calculate it, or, more likely, do differentiate it.

Comment: Is it really a calc 1 problem? It cannot really be expressed in closed form.

Comment: this integral leads to a hypergeometric function

Comment: we need to find dy/dx

Comment: i forgot to put that there, i'm sorry

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+(t%5E3%2B1)%5E%7B1%2F2%7D+dt

Comment: Have you tried [Leibniz's integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)? If so, notice that the integrand is NOT a function of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.
- Since the upper limit is $x^2$, remember to use chain rule.